# iPhone 4 internet tethering problem

Tags: iphone, tethering

I'm a user of Movistar (Spain) iPhone 4 mobile. I'm trying to activate the internet tethering and seems to all work fine. By default can be selectable. So, I put it on and connect it to my laptop (PC).

I can't no where select to connect with my iPhone. How I have to managed the connection?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you have iTunes installed on your PC.
2. Enable tethering via USB on your iPhone.
3. Connect your iPhone to your PC via USB.

A new driver will automatically be installed and you should be able to use a Local Area Connection that will have been created for you.